# (Server) Encrypt data in PostgreSQL - Decrypt on the Client-Site

Tags: postgresql, erlang, base64, base32

I have Fedora22 and working for a Messanger-App. 
Now we want to Update our System. In the old Version we used Mnesia-Database.
Now we want to switch to PostgreSql.

I am not sure, but PostgreSQL save all the Data in base32.
The Client needs the data in base64. So i dont want to use allways encode/2 and decode/2 methods.
Is it possibile to switch the whole Database from base32 in base64.

Sorry for my english.

> **Update 02.08.2016 / 16:21 ** 
>   My Problem is, when the Client get the encrypt data, and tries to decrypt, I get an Error with "Bad Base 64". I thought that is because PostgreSQL save the data in base32. I was sure that i read like that.
>   So is it my fault because I didnt use the dataypes correctly?

An example of one Table-Schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE users (
    id varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    jid bytea, 
    name bytea, 
    pic bytea, 
    role bytea, 
    department bytea, 
    room bytea, 
    phone bytea, 
    email bytea,
    `tag1 varchar(255) REFERENCES tags, 
    tag2 varchar(255) REFERENCES tags, 
    tag3 varchar(255) REFERENCES tags, 
    status_msg bytea, 
    status_duration bytea,status_img bytea
);", Connection),
```

Comment: PostgreSQL does not save data in base32 encoding.

Comment: Show the relevant table's schemas

Comment: The only columns in that it makes sense to use `bytea` is `pic` which I suppose means picture and `status_img`. They are binary.

Comment: What data are you encrypting? How are you encrypting the data? How are you decrypting the data? Please add some relevant code.

Comment: I want to encrypt/decrypt the Datatype Strings/ Binarys. In example all Information of the User, Name, Telephonenumber etc. everyhing is saved as String/Binary. For the Pictures, we upload them and save only the link as a String.<br> The encrypt is from the Server site - this two function <br> `Crypt = crypto:block_encrypt(aes_cfb128, ?KEY, ?IV, Text), base64:encode(Crypt)` <br> And for the decrypte the Same: <br> ` B64 = base64:decode(Text),
  crypto:block_decrypt(aes_cfb128, ?KEY, ?IV, B64)` <br> The Client-Site decrypt in the same way.

Comment: I have to added: When we use the Mensia-Database, we saved everything in binary everything workes fine. The problems comes with PostgreSQL